# Returning variable value, while the variable name is in a string

Tags: c#, parsing, variables

I have a double variable name and a string declared as this:

```
public double dblvar = 0;
public string str = "dblvar";
```

What I'm trying to do is returning `0`, by using the variable `str`

There are a few guides on how to parse a string into a double, or how to declare a new variable name from a string, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Something I tried and is not working quite right but might be close was this:

```
double test = (double)this.GetType().GetField("dblvar").GetValue(this);
```

But even if this is close to the solution, it demands I know before hand that it's a `double`. While in my example it's in fact a `double`, other variables I'm using can be `int`.

Any suggestions? I'm not even sure this would be possible.

Regards,

Edit:

Many people commented asking for details on what I'm trying to do.
What I'm trying to do is exactly what is there, it's a public variable not embebed in a different class, it's not an XY problem what I want to do is exactly what is described, and I don't want to do it with a Dictionary, that would involve updating hundreds of variables I already have.
What I want to know if this is possible somehow, exactly as it is described.

Comment: In what context do you want to get the field values? If they're class fields then I believe they need to be public to be accessible by Reflection.

Comment: You can reflect over private members if you have enough rights. But, what are you trying to do, if we know that, we can probably give you a better answer

Comment: they are public variables

Comment: If the field is not public, you need to specify that when calling `GetField`. There are a number of [flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=net-7.0) you can pass to tell it exactly what to look for. In this case, you probably want the second argument to be `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Comment: But also, this seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain what you're actually trying to do rather than just your intended solution. There is likely a much better solution.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you actually want a `Dictionary<string, double>`. Then you get your double value in this way: `double d = dict["doublevar"];`. Use [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=net-7.0) if you are not sure that the key exists.

Comment: @TimSchmelter no, it's not that, I already have about 100 variables that I don't want to redefine

Comment: It's working, but the how to handle the possibility of having doubles/ints?

Comment: _"I already have about 100 variables that I don't want to redefine"_ - yes you do. You just don't know, yet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The code I've put together is working in fact in a fresh project. Thanks for the replies.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public double dblvar = 3;
        public string str = "dblvar";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MessageBox.Show(dblvar.ToString() + " " + str);

            double test = (double)this.GetType().GetField("dblvar").GetValue(this);
            MessageBox.Show(test.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this works, any Dev with any experience with reflection will recommend to prefer a redesign, so you can avoid this.